# create XSL transformation that transforms xml to XHTML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

Like the title says I need to transform an XML file to XHTML, the results must include a CSS file that I have. But I cant seem to get the output correct, when i right click and view the source its still look like an XML file. I thing I saw somewhere a software that convertet my XML and XSL to an XHTML output.

Any Ideas ? I post my code if its any help.

Thanks
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE thesaurus SYSTEM "dictionary.dtd"> --> <!--bortkommenterad så att man ska kunna validera jämte emot xsd schema-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="thesaurus.xsl"?> <!-- Hamtar xsl styleesheet-->
<thesaurus> <!--Rootelementet kan enbart finnas 1 gang -->
  <dictionary> <!--resten av elementen kan nastlas in i elementet.-->
    <language>Engelsk</language>
    <author>
      <firstname>Felipe</firstname>
      <lastname>Otarola</lastname>
    </author>
    <word type="1">Stroll</word> <!--eftersom vi bara behover anvanda 10st ord ar det batre att ge dem olika typer istallet for att nastla in dem i varsina element.-->
    <word type="2">Tender</word>
    <word type="3">Agents</word>
    <word type="4">Partial</word>
    <word type="5">Logotype</word>
    <word type="6">Pretend</word>
    <word type="7">Color</word>
    <word type="8">Silent</word>
    <word type="9">Foundations</word>
    <word type="10">Grain</word>
  </dictionary>
</thesaurus>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> 
      <body>
      <div id="wrap"> 

      <div id ="title"> <xsl:apply-templates select="//language"/> ordlista</div> 

        <div id="author">
          Författare:  <xsl:apply-templates select="//author"/> </div>
      <p class="words"><xsl:apply-templates select="//word">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates></p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you all

Comment: Why do you care what 'view source' shows?

Comment: Why do you think the output is incorrect? The output is an XHtml document, exactly as produced by the transformation -- and you can view it (not the source!) in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run you xsl against your XML using a tool such as Oxygen I get the output below.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
     <div id="title">Engelsk ordlista</div>
     <div id="author">
        Författare:  
        Felipe
        Otarola

     </div>
     <p class="words">Agents<br>Color<br>Foundations<br>Grain<br>Logotype<br>Partial<br>Pretend<br>Silent<br>Stroll<br>Tender<br></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it by opening the xml with Internet Explorer I see the result you would get if the above html were displayed by the browser.

So everything is working.

You seem to have an expectation that view source will show you the intermediate HTML rather than the actual source - the XML. Your expectation appears to be incorrect not your code

Comment: Hey thank you. I don't know where I got the idea of the output html file. tried the oxygen tool and its showing the same as you.
Well. thank you alot :)